# How to multiply rows of list by another list?

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

I have two lists (`l1`, `l2`) with arbitrary dimensions, say `l1.shape = (3,2)` and `l2.shape = (2,2,2)`.

```
l1 = np.array([[1, 10], 
               [2, 20], 
               [3, 30]])

l2 = np.array([[[1, 2], 
                [3, 4]],

               [[5, 6],
                [7, 8]]],)
```

I want to multiply each row of `l1` by the entire `l2` and save each result in another list. Therefore, creating a new list (`l3`) with an extra dimension as follows, `l3.shape = (3,2,2,2)`. So I expect:

```
l3 = np.array([[[[1,   20], 
                 [3,   40]],
                [[5,   60],
                 [7,   80]]],

               [[[2,   40], 
                 [6,   80]],
                [[10, 120],
                 [14, 160]]],

               [[[3,   60], 
                 [9,  120]],
                [[15, 180],
                 [21, 240]]]])
```

I have tried multiplying row lists separately using that numpy can broadcast arrays so they have the same size. However, I haven't been able to do it with lists of **arbitrary size** and this is important for my application.

I have tried:

```
l3 = l1[0,:] * l2

array([[[1, 20], 
        [3, 40]],
       [[5, 60],
        [7, 80]]])
```

But, I cannot be able to create the index of l1 automatically in a general way so the number of dimensions of both lists doesn't matter.

Comment: you can try einsum, somthing like `np.einsum('ab,bcd -> abcd',l1,l2)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
(l1[:,:,None,None]*l2.T).swapaxes(1,3)
```

This should give you the desired output